# Is there a way to auto update a dataprovider in a flex list?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, list, refresh

Is there a way so that every time the list is changed (data add, data deleted, etc.), the list will re-update or "refresh?"

Answer (score 0):

Flex provides data-binding for this purpose.

Read more here : http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/10/01/data-binding-in-flex/

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke 'invalidateDisplayList' to refresh the datagrid result.You can also refer to

http://devharbor.blogspot.com/2008/10/refresh-flex-datagrid.html